# Video Streaming for Mobile App

Tags: ios, http, amazon-web-services, nginx, video-streaming

I'm building an iOS app for a client that allows users to pay a subscription and unlock additional content within the app.  Part of the additional content will be videos which need to be streamed from a server... but I'm not sure whether we should use a hosting service (like Amazon CloudFront or Wowza, perhaps?) or roll our own solution.

Have any of you had experience with either of these options? I looks like this is supported natively by [nginx](http://nginx.com/products/streaming-media-delivery/), which we're currently using as our rProxy, but I'd like to hear some thoughts about that. I would be somewhat concerned about saturating our server's 1Gb network connection too...

Whatever the solution, we must be able to verify a person's account before they can access the video content. Variable bitrate is also desirable, and the ability to support >500 concurrent users. This company is also a new startup, so subscription costs are an important factor.

Answer (score 0):

It is usually best to deploy streaming-specific software or services instead of generic HTTP servers such as Nginx. For Wowza, as an example, here's a quick list of features for this type of workflow.

- Performance and scalability. You can do a quick comparison on playing back concurrent streams (using load test tools) and see what kind of load can be handled by an HTTP server vs Wowza.
- Monitoring. Statistics collection is also integrated with Wowza, which may prove beneficial for start-up companies that need to leverage this kind of data mining.
- Security. Wowza also has several options that you can use, such as Secure Token. For example, you can configure your mobile app to query the user's IP address once you determine that they are authorized to receive the stream. You can then generate a hash token based on this IP address and the stream they are authorized for, and only allow playback with the valid token. You can also expire these tokens.
- Manager UI. Not as attractive for developers/sys admins, but users can take advantage of a relatively intuitive UI.
- Extensibility. Wowza has REST and Java API that can allow you to add custom modules or integrate third-party systems. For example, you can use a custom module that monitors stream connection time, and cuts off any connections that are longer than x number of hours.